# Display hex as binary string DB2

Tags: sql, function, binary, db2, hex

I've been searching far and wide on the 'net to find a way to display a field that is "varchar for bit data" in DB2 as just a binary string.  The data initially inserted into that field was a binary string, but upon retrieval it gets converted into hex.  I'm thinking there must be some function in DB2 that must achieve this but I have found nothing online.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you really want. You cannot normally "display" non-character data. Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You really want to see it as a string of ones and zeros instead of hex?

I don't believe that's possible.  There's a BINARY() function (in DB2 for IBM i at least) , but it doesn't return ones & zeros.

You could write your own UDF.